# IIS Webdeploy: copy files to client

Tags: iis, msdeploy, webdeploy

I am trying to copy some files to a destination Folder (which should be no problem with Webdeploy) and after that process I would like to get these files on the client (the computer which is starting the msdeploy process).
There seem to be a lot of examples on how to copy files to a server, but I could not find any about geting files from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is not currently supported by MSDeploy. Workarounds that I can think of include:

- Defining a [`postSync`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569089%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) argument that copies files to a directory accessible via FTP
- Install MSDeploy on the client and have the server trigger a separate deployment back to the client (this would require that the client be publically accessible)